# C# arrays [,] to Java, concept of specific array

Tags: java, c#

I'm re-writing C# code to Java. I'm facing a type of **array** not supported by Java. `int[,] distance;`

So here are my questions, what is this ? **[,]**
Is it the same thing as **[ ][ ]** ?

I think if I write in java `int [ ] [ ] distance;` it will work the same way but not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `[,]` Is it the same thing as `[][]` ?

No. I'll use `int` as the element type to make things simpler. An `int[,]` is a *rectangular array*. It's a single object, which is indexed by two dimensions. Each element of the array Note that you can have more dimensions as well, e.g. `int[,,] x = new int[10, 20, 30]`.

There's no concept of accessing "a row" or "a column" of a rectangular array - so

```
int[,] rectangular = new int[5, 3];
int[] row = rectangular[2]; // Invalid
```

Compare that with an `int[][]` - that's an *array of arrays*, also known as a *jagged array*. Each element of the array is an `int[]`... either a null reference, or a reference to an `int[]` object. Each of the elements may refer to an array of a different length, e.g.

```
int[][] jagged = new int[][]
{
    new int[0],
    new int[1],
    new int[2]
};
```

Here, `jagged[1][0]` is valid, as are `jagged[2][1]` and `jagged[2][2]`... but `jagged[0][0]` would be invalid, as `jagged[0]` has no elements. And of course you can access individual "rows" in the jagged array:

```
int[] row = jagged[1];
```

Note that multiple elements can be the same reference, too. For example:

```
int[][] jagged = new int[2][];
jagged[0] = new int[1];
jagged[1] = jagged[0];
jagged[0][0] = 10;
System.out.printn(jagged[1][0]); // Also 10! (References to the same array.)
```

And then of course you mix and match, e.g. `int[][,]` where each element of the top-level jagged array is a rectangular array. I'd strongly recommend against doing that.

Comment: It was a clear explanation of the concept ! I learned new words and understood the concept of rectangular array & jagged array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same, but it's the mapping that exists. It will work the same way for your application.

The key difference is that the C# `[,]` syntax guarantees a rectangular array, and the C# and Java `[][]` syntax allows jagged arrays unless you guarantee each inner array is the same length.

If you are using slicing of the multi-dimension array in C#, you'll need to create or use helper functions to get that same functionality.

Comment: Well, the "mapping" exists for some uses, but not others. You can't take a "slice" of a rectangular array for example, in the same way that you can with a jagged array...

Comment: ah, good point. I should say for the case of individual indexed access, it's straightforward.